# How to query data that the status remain unchanged in PieCloudDB?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this in my PieCloudDB database.

| user_id | quarterly_log | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 1 | high |
| 110 | 2 | high |
| 110 | 3 | high |
| 110 | 4 | high |
| 120 | 1 | low |
| 120 | 2 | high |
| 120 | 3 | low |
| 120 | 4 | high |
| 130 | 1 | high |
| 130 | 2 | high |
| 130 | 3 | high |
| 130 | 4 | high |

How can I on query the rows whose status are always 'high' that never change from the beginning to the end of the quarter.

| user_id | quarterly_log | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 1 | high |
| 110 | 2 | high |
| 110 | 3 | high |
| 110 | 4 | high |
| 130 | 1 | high |
| 130 | 2 | high |
| 130 | 3 | high |
| 130 | 4 | high |

Answer (score 1):

You can use the not exists operator in your database:

```
SELECT *
FROM   PieCloudDB x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   PieCloudDB y
                   WHERE  x.user_id = y.user_id AND y.status != 'high')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group by `user_id` and calculate how much statuses has value `high` in all 4 quarters:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id IN (
   -- Select all user_id that has all 4 quarter marked as 'status = high'
   SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE status = 'high' GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
)
```